# Fetch request throwing errors on my swiftui core data login system

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

i'm new to swiftui and core data and am trying to get a basic login system working but whenever i try to use request.fecthLimit it throws loads of errors so i was wondering if anyone could look through my code and work out why its doing this. this code is trying to do a very basic sign up and login menu.
code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var userDetails:  FetchedResults<UserDetails>
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var passwords: String = ""
    @State private var name: String = ""
    @State private var attemptusername: String = ""
    @State private var attemptpasswords: String = ""
    @FetchRequest (sortDescriptors: [])var fetchRequest: FetchedResults<UserDetails>
    
    let request = basicFetchRequest()
    request.fetchLimit
    


    static func basicFetchRequest() -> FetchRequest<UserDetails> {
        //FetchRequest(entity: UserDetails.entity(), sortDescriptors: [])
    //}
    
    

    
    
    
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(userDetails) { UserDetails in
                Text(UserDetails.email ?? "Unknown")
            }
            List(userDetails) { UserDetails in
                Text(UserDetails.password ?? "Unknown")
            }
            
            TextField("Email Address", text: $username)
            TextField("Password", text: $passwords)
            TextField("Name", text: $name)
            Button("Sign Up"){
                let userDetails = UserDetails(context: moc)
                userDetails.id = UUID()
                userDetails.email = "\(username)"
                userDetails.password = "\(passwords)"
                userDetails.name = "\(name)"
                
                try? moc.save()
            }
            TextField("Enter Email Address", text: $attemptusername)
            TextField("Enter Password", text: $attemptpasswords)
            
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

i am reaaly confused

Comment: When your code causes error messages, your question really needs to include those errors, because they usually have useful information. Not including the errors makes it harder for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is really a mess but I think you want something like this

```
@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Self.basicFetchRequest()) var fetchRequest: FetchedResults<UserDetails>

static func basicFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<UserDetails> {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<UserDetails>()
    request.fetchLimit = 1
    return request
}
```

That is to use a constructor that takes an NSFetchRequest and then have a static method that creates that NSFetchRequest and sets the limit

Comment: I want to thank you for the clarification, like they did not.

Comment: i have seemed to run into a different error where when i have put this code in there error has occured saying: ''cannot find 'NSFetchRequest' in scope" on these two lines: static func basicFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<UserDetails> {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<UserDetails>(). Im really unsure on the probelm

Comment: You can’t work with Core Data without knowing the basics so I would suggest you find some tutorials. As for the error, you need to import the framework, `import CoreData`